# Getting enum-style values from within a class?

Tags: php, enums

I'm trying to use an interface as a substitute for the lack of enums in PHP, but it does not seem to be working the way I want it to.

Here is the code:

```
interface Brands
{
    const abrand = "A Brand";
    const anotherbrand = "Another Brand";
}

class Product
{
    private $brand;

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function getBrand() {
        return Brands::$this->brand;
    }
    public function setBrand($value) {
        $this->brand = $value;
    }
}

$product = new Product();
$product->setBrand("aproduct");

echo $product->getBrand();
```

Can someone explain Why is the output is `abrand` instead of `A Brand`?

Comment: Why do you use `Brands::$this->brand` instead of simple `Brands::abrand`? It's weird that you'd like to mimic enums while still wanting to use the dynamism of PHP with constructs such as this `Brands::$this->brand`. Anyway, it seems that the `Brands::` prefix is ignored altogether and it only returns the value of `$this->brand`.

Comment: oh man, this got me thinking... that was dumb (see answer)

Comment: Haha, no problem. I have a record of being a good rubber duck (for those not understanding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was stupid.

I should have been doing `$product->setBrand(Brands::abrand);` instead of `$product->setBrand("aproduct");`

:/